# Get key from JSON by string using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, .net

I need to be able to get data from JSON using JSON.NET.

```
{
  "labels": {
    "start" : {
      "action" : "ASK",
      "message" : "What do you want to do, {name}?",
      "responses" : {
        "kill" : "GOTO label3"
      }
    },
    "label3" : {
      "action" : "END",
      "message" : "Thanks for playing."
    }
  }
}
```

This is my C# code: `dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourcejson);`
This puts the JSON into an object that I can access like this, or similar:
`Console.WriteLine(json.labels.start.responses.kill);`
However, I need to specify which key to retrieve based on a string, for example, retrieving "kill" based on a C# string with the contents of "kill". If I had another response in responses, I could just change the C# string to the name of the specified key and it would retrieve it. How exactly could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference would be to deserialize into a `JObject`.

For example: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(sourceJson);`

Then, you can reference the keys using standard C# indexers.

```cs
var jObj = JsonConvert.DerserializeObject<JObject>(sourceJson);
var kill = jObj["labels"]["start"]["responses"]["kill"]?.ToString();
```

However, make sure that you have the appropriate null checks in various places as it isn't "type-safe" code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue using a `dynamic` object you could just replace your print statement with `json.labels.start.responses["kill"]` as shown below;

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var sourcejson = @"{
                  ""labels"": {
                    ""start"" : {
                      ""action"" : ""ASK"",
                      ""message"" : ""What do you want to do, {name}?"",
                      ""responses"" : {
                        ""kill"" : ""GOTO label3""
                      }
                    },
                    ""label3"" : {
                      ""action"" : ""END"",
                      ""message"" : ""Thanks for playing.""
                    }
                  }
                }";

    dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sourcejson);

    Console.WriteLine(json.labels.start.responses["kill"]);
}
```

Your serialized object will have a `Dictionary<string, object>` of all attributes and you can access the values by their keys.